# mapsActivity async method to get JSON

Tags: android

I've created a basic mapsActivity and I want to get coordinates from a JSON string. The method I use to get the JSON string from the server is Async so my JSON string is showing as empty when I use the debug tool.

I saw that onActivityResult could help for my problem, but when I type "@Override" it says "Method does not override method from its superclass". What should I do to get my JSON string with the data in MapsActivity ?

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

String json_string; //ici seront stockées les information concernant les établissements

protected static String JSON_STRING;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        json_string = data.getStringExtra("JSON_string");
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {



    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, getJSON.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);


    /*
    LatLng flams = new LatLng(47.221626, -1.557679);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(flams).title("Le flams"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(flams));*/
}
```

}

getJSON.java

```
public class getJSON extends AppCompatActivity {

String json_string;
protected static String JSON_STRING; //string for both getJSON and mapsActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new BackgroundTask().execute();

}


public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    String json_url = "the URL of my server";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((json_string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(json_string+"\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim(); <= while this shows the data

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

       public BackgroundTask() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSON_STRING=result;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("JSON_string", JSON_STRING);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, when you start activity `getJSON` then it will take time to get the data from the server side that is the reason you can't get the value of json_string immediately. By the way, please follow my guideline to make the logic properly.

When an Activity A `startActivityForResult` then will get the result in the `onActivityResult` method.

In your code when you start the activity `getJSON`, the JSON_STRING need to send back to the `mapsActivity` as the code below:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("JSON_string", JSON_STRING);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
```

You will get the result in the method, `onActivityResult` in the `mapsActivity`:

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         json_string = data.getStringExtra("JSON_string");
      }
   }
```

Feel free ask me if it is not clear.

Comment: When I try to add an Override for onActivityResult it says "Method does not override method from its superclass" is that normal ?

Comment: @MrRog85 Does your `mapsActivity` extends from an `Activity`? If yes you will see the `@Override` method

Comment: It's ok for the Override, but the json_string still shows as empty in the debug tool when I put a Breakpoint on it (inside the onActivityResult)

Comment: How is the get json_string in `BackgroundTask` task? Does it have the data? Remember set the result back as I answered above.

Comment: Yes the BackgroundTask get the data, and I've made the change in my code just like in your post. Do you want the full MapsActivity class ? Could it help ?

Comment: You need to update the result in the `onPostExecute` method of `BackgroundTask` class, not from the method of `getJSON` activity.

Comment: I've just updated my post so you can see my onPostExecute method, I've changed it as you said but json_string still shows up as null in MapsActivity

Comment: @MrRog85. You need to remove the set result in the `onCreate` of `getJSON` activity.

Comment: Just changed it aswell, stil null for json_string in MapsActivity. But JSON_STRING does have the values in getJSON (they show up in the logs). Could it be the debugger's fault ?

Comment: Where do you call BackgroundTask to execute?

Comment: I call the BackgroundTask inside the OnCreate of getJson, and getJson is called from intent inside the onMapReady method in MapsActivity. I've updated my getJSON on my post

Comment: It works ! It was due to the debug tool ! Thanks a million